# Eclipse Luna on Windows with C/C++ and SDL 2

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, sdl-2, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to work on a project that uses C++, SDL2 (libsdl2), and SDL2_mixer (libsdl2-mixer) libraries.

I already downloaded and installed the Eclipse Luna CDT from the marketplace and successfully opened the project. However, how do I install the other two libraries? I have them downloaded but am unsure on where to begin. Thank you!

I'm using a Windows 7 laptop with Eclipse Luna and the project is a cloned repository from Github.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial covers setting up an SDL 2.0 project in Eclipse on Windows. It isn't the same Eclipse release but it should be almost if not exactly the same process.

http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-eclipse-windows/

The extra library, SDL2_mixer, should be installed in the same location as the SDL2 and linked in the same way.

Also, make sure to have any dll's in the runtime exe directory for both SDL2 and any additional SDL libraries.